# Convergence result on Cornish Fisher expansion of binomial distribution

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence, approximation-theory

Since it is known that Cornish Fisher expansion of quantiles does not have guaranteed convergence for all distribution, I wonder specifically if any convergence result is known in literature for CF expansion of Binomial distribution (E.g., for $X \sim B(n,p)$, is the CF expansion of $F_X^{-1}(q), 0 \leq q \leq 1,$ guaranteed to converge?). I would also greatly appreciate any provable loss bounds if we only expand up to the first few cumulants.

Just as a side note: CF expansion seems to be used pretty frequently in coding packages (e.g., Python, Matlab) in approximation of quantiles of binomial distribution, so I am assuming some provable guarantees are known in this field.